# Loading SVG image file does not work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, svg, laravel-8

I want to load an svg image file like this:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="" disabled></object>
     <option value="ir" selected><object data="{{ asset('assets/img/flags/ir.svg') }}" width="300" height="300"> </option>
</select>
```

But nothing load in the select option!

So how to load this `ir.svg` image file which is properly placed in `public\assets\img\flags`?

Comment: If you type in the URL for the image in the address bar it loads? And if you look at the HTML code it refers correctly with a relative URL?

Comment: set file **ir.svg** to 664 and retry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, solved it through this:

Place the image in the public folder, no subdirectory.

Call the image as so:

```
<img src="/my_img.png" alt="Logo" class="h-8 w-8 mr-2">
```